# Why arent the views being added to this UIAnimator?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, uikit

Im adding views to an animator like so:

```
-(void)drawCellLikeViews{

    //2. Add Animator
    _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];

    //Alloc array
    viewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

    for (int numberOfViews = 0; numberOfViews < 5; numberOfViews++) {
        //Create views
        UIView* cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self addSubview:cell];

        [viewsArray addObject:cell];
    }


    //3. Add Gravity
    _gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:viewsArray];
    [_animator addBehavior:_gravity];

    //4. Add boundaries
    _collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:viewsArray];
    _collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    [_animator addBehavior:_collision];


    //8. Add ItemProperties' Behaviors
    UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:viewsArray];
    itemBehaviour.elasticity = 0.6;

    //9. itemBehaviour.action = ^{};
    [_animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour];

    NSLog(@"viewcount %d", [[self subviews] count]);
}
```

I only see one drop down to the bottom.

Comment: Are you seeing the others not drop down?  Because it looks like they all start in the same place, and have the same behaviour, so they would move in unison and overlay each other, giving the appearance of one object falling.

Comment: Yeah I did "fix" it that way. I was just wondering why though, if they react with each other, wouldnt they end up stacked even though they all started in the same place.

Comment: It seems as though they interact with edge collisions, not with understanding that they are occupying the same space and adjusting their position accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@HalR is correct—your views *are* being added to the animator; they're just all being added at the same time with the same starting attributes, so they will all behave in exactly the same way and appear as one item. And yes, by default, the collision behavior's mode is `UICollisionBehaviorModeEverything`, meaning its items should collide with each other and with the boundaries. Yet, by implying `UICollisionBehaviorModeEverything` and placing all of the items on top of each other, you've created an impossible scenario wherein you've explicitly told the edges of each item to overlap, but you've told the animator that they're not allowed to overlap. The animator's behavior at that point is undefined—I think it just ignores whatever physics rule you've manually broken, but it can get much weirder than that. In [WWDC 2013 Session 206 (Getting Started with UIKit Dynamics)](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/206xex2xws29m12p69m7s169q/206/206.pdf?dl=1), Apple at one point says "don't expect the impossible" saying that "you can create setups which don't have solutions" and showing overlapping items with collision behaviors set as an example. In other words, they saw this coming, and they just don't want you to do it. ;)

The way to make this work, of course, would just be to give each of the items a starting position that doesn't overlap with other items' starting positions, or to add them all to where you're adding them now, only a few seconds apart from each other so the last one can fall out of the way.

Comment: or what I did which is just set up the lower boundary by itself :)